# 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'imagepreview' is undefined

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-2014-express

This is my cshtml code For uploading imageFile am getting error:

```
<div class="control-group">                                                   <label class="control-label"for="inputName"><i class="icon-user"></i>Company Logo</label>
<div class="controls">
<input id="BtnImg" type="file" class="uploadfile" name="Photo" onchange="imagepreview(this);" />
<span id="spError1" class="error"></span>

<img id="imgprw" src="~/images/profile.jpg" style="width:130px; height:130px" />
</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That error means that the function "imagepreview" does not exist in your page. You need to either include a file which implements this script or have the script defined in this page in order for this to work.

See this page for more information.
https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/16/understanding-undefined-and-preventing-referenceerrors/